# Google Cloud Adding a user to a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I want to be able to programatically add a user to a project that exists in google cloud. I can do this via the console by going to Iam and admin, selecting a project, then searching for a user, selecting a role and adding them. Furthermore, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) seem to say this should be possible

> Project owners can grant access to team members to access project's
>   resources and APIs by granting IAM roles to team members. You can
>   grant a role to a team member using the Cloud Platform Console, the
>   cloud command-line tool, or the setIamPolicy() method.

But the API [seems](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects) to be missing this method.

I can grant users access to particular resources, but I cant give them the same kind of *all resource* access level that I can from the console.

What API call can I use to, say, grant a given user read-only access to all the resources in a given project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right where you linked it :)

What you want to do is:
1. [Get current policy.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy)
That will give you a JSON response showing you what the structure should be like.
2. Make your changes. If there is already an entry with `roles/viewer`, append to the `members` list, otherwise create the entry:

```
...
{
   "role": "roles/viewer",
   "members": [
    "user:your.friend@gmail.com"
   ]
  },
...
```

3. [Set the new policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy).

For a [list of possible roles look here.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Comment: This method requires I specify a resource. My understanding is that a project is not a resource.

How can I use this method to grant a user access to ALL resources in a project?

Comment: That's just the name of the project. I agree, the docs could be a little clearer here. Actually setting the IAM policy on individual resources (like compute engine instances, storage buckets etc.) is done through their respective APIs, not this method.

Comment: @RobertLacock Is this method working for you with a project name? Using either project name or project ID gives me "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"body_resource\": Cannot find field."